# Breaker to Sub-Panel keeps tripping

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, subpanel

I have a 30 amp double-throw breaker in my main panel that feeds a sub-panel in my shop.  A few weeks ago, one of the 2 circuits in the shop stopped working.  Then, a few days ago, the breaker in the main panel to the shop tripped.  When I attempted to re-set it, it would hum for a few seconds and then trip again.

I shut off the sub-panel's main breaker and tried to re-set the breaker with the same result (loud hum then trip).  I replaced the breaker in the main to the same result.  I'm at a loss as to what to do next.  Replace the sub-panel main?  Replace sub-panel's individual breakers?  Replace the sub-panel?  As far as I can tell the wires to the sub-panel are intact (and the panel's ground is still connected to the grounding wire).

Comment: What make and model are both panels in question?  Is the breaker in the main panel getting warm/hot when it trips?

Comment: Try disconnecting and capping the hots entering the sub panel. If the main panel breaker still trips, you’ve probably got damaged feed wires

Comment: Could you try physical inspection of the panels and wiring, particularly the cable or conduit between house and shop?  Is it in conduit? Is it 3-wire or 4-wire?  *Has anything changed recently? Any digging or work done?*

Comment: First try just turning all the breakers in the sub panel off and see if there is a problem, then try the main, trying to cut the problem in half, right now we don’t know if in the panel, main or feeder.

Comment: I've turned off all the breakers in the sub panel, and capping the hots on the sub panel.  No change.  I can't see any issues above ground at the shop, I will look under the house.  We've had some work done recently on the opposite side of the house, but nothing near the panel or where the wires to the shop would run.